# Google Analytics Query Explorer - Custom Metric (alias)

Tags: google-analytics, google-reporting-api

Is it possible to have alias for custom defined metric in [Google Analytics Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)?

Currently I get table column name: Custom Metric 1 Value.

Comment: no the query explorer just displays results directly from the API,  and this really isn't a programing question is it.

Comment: How can I then define alias for custom metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Analytics Query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) is mainly a development testing tool.  It returns the information directly from the Google Analytics API, using the raw [dimension and metric names](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

The correct name via the API for custom metrics is `GA:metric1 - ga:metric20` or  `Custom Metric 1 - Custom Metric 20`.

You cant change that to make or make an alias.

If you want to do something like that you would have to code it directly yourself using the [Google Analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/)